# Does size of row or column effect aggregation queries in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, query-performance

Consider the following table definition:

```
    Column       |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |    Default    
-----------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------
 id              | uuid                     |           | not null | 
 reference_id    | text                     |           |          | 
 data            | jsonb                    |           |          | 
 tag             | character varying(255)   |           |          | 
 created_at      | timestamp with time zone |           |          | 
 updated_at      | timestamp with time zone |           |          | 
 is_active       | boolean                  |           | not null | true
 status          | integer                  |           |          | 0
 message         | text                     |           |          | 
 batch_id        | uuid                     |           | not null | 
 config          | jsonb                    |           |          |
```

Overall table size to be over 500M and every row in the table contains a data column to have a JSON of over 50MB.

**Questions -**

Does the size of the `data` column effect aggregation such as `count`?
Assume we are running the below query -

```
select count(*)
from table 
where batch_id = '88f30539-32d7-445c-8d34-f1da5899175c';
```

Does the size of the `data` column effect aggregation such as `sum`?
Assume we are running the below queries -

Query 1 -

```
select sum(data->>'count'::int)
from table 
where batch_id = '88f30539-32d7-445c-8d34-f1da5899175c';
```

Query 2 -

```
select sum(jsonb_array_length(data->'some_array'))
from table 
where batch_id = '88f30539-32d7-445c-8d34-f1da5899175c';
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to know is to measure.

Once the data is large enough to always be TOASTed, then its size will no longer affect the performance of queries which do not need to access the TOASTed data contents, like your first one.  Your last two do need to access the contents and their performance will depend on the size.